# Storing document.getElementById in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, document, getelementbyid

I have this script that is supposed to change the text of the button when the button is clicked.

```
<body>
   <button onclick="toggleText(this);" id="id">Edit</button>
</body>

function toggleText(element){
    var text = document.getElementById(element.id).textContent;

    if (text == 'Edit') {
        text = 'Done';
    } else {
        text = 'Edit';
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It only works when you put `document.getElementById(element.id).textContent` directly into the if statements.

How do I get the variable to store properly?

Comment: You can store the result of `getElementById` to a variable, but the properties on it aren't passed by reference, so you can't do that... `var y = document.getElementById(element.id); y.textContent = "done";`

Comment: Why not just `text = element.textContent`?

Comment: I see what you're saying tymeJV. Can't believe I didn't think of that David.

Comment: *"But it doesn't work."* JavaScript is pass/assign **by value**. Assigning a new value to a variable will not change the value of another variable or property (exceptions: global and `with` scope).

Comment: Got it. I'm used to Lua where it does work like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you already get the element, you don't need to get it again. You can just use element.

But the reason why you can't change it is that you're only changing the variable that contains the text. It does not point to the element's properties. You need to use this:

```
function toggleText(element){
  var text = element.textContent;

  if (text == 'Edit') {
    element.textContent = 'Done';
  } else {
    element.textContent = 'Edit';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you access `document.getElementById(element.id).textContent` you get the value of it, not the reference. So changes to it won't affect the element.

But when you assign element to variable, it gets reference to it.

```
var element = document.getElementById(element.id);
if (element.textContent == 'Edit') {
        element.textContent = 'Done';
    } else {
        element.textContent = 'Edit';
}
```

Comment: `var element = document.getElementById(element.id);` is not necessary.

Comment: I know that he has element basically as argument.but he wants to know why his code doesn't work. so I think this is better explanation.

Comment: Any answer that repeats redundancy is a problematic answer, in terms of teaching; note that I'm not saying you're wrong, just that you need to go a little further to have a *good* answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

#### index.js

```
var mainText = document.getElementById("mainText").value;
document.write(mainText);
```

#### index.html

```
<textarea id="mainText"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

As tymeJV commented, you can store by reference the element you get by id. Its property is stored by value. Instead store the element in a variable and access its property from the variable.

```
var text = document.getElementById(element.id);

if (text.textContent == 'Edit') {
     text.textContent = 'Done';
} else {
    text.textContent = 'Edit';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Is jquery an option ?

I used to do something like :

```
var a = $('#theid');
A.something
```

Comment: I mean, in a DRY principle logic, the thing you gonna code to make it work is already coded in jquery's core

Comment: And since the event already gives them the element, why would they want to add a dependency to a large library and use that?

Comment: Because recoding the wheel is never a good option. Because nowadays, in the frontend world, size is not the same mater anymore. Because Jqlite exists.